# Getting fully custom Facebook Login Button on Android

Tags: android, facebook

for my app i want my facebook button fully customizable. That means for me to no use the `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` and use a normal android button instead. To make it work i tried this solution with getting an `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));`but it throws an error saying:

> Cannot resolve method logInWithReadPermissions(anonymous
>   android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.util.List)

Can you please help?

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_fb_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_login);

        btn_fb_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });

    }

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```

Here 'this' points to the onClickListener.  But it should point to 'activity' or 'fragment'.

So replace `this` with `YourActivityName.this`.